# passing and storing template function pointer for EventDriver

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I am developing a framework for event dispatcher driver in C++ functional style. In this framework user can register an action for an event with the driver. Later when the event occurs, the driver will dispatch the event using registered action as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template < class ... ES >
class EventDriver {
  public :
    template<class T> using Func = void (*)(T& x);

    tuple< Func< ES > ... > actions;

    // Func< > default_action;

    template < class EVENT>
    void setAction ( void (*fp )(EVENT& ) ){
        std::get< Func<EVENT> >( actions )=fp;
    }

    template < class EVENT>
    void notify( EVENT& e ){
        Func<EVENT> f = std::get< Func<EVENT> >( actions );

        if( f ){
            f( e );
        }else{
         printf("Could not process event. No registered action found \n");
        }

    }
};

// TEST the EventDriver
//
class EventAA{};
class EventBB{};
class EventCC{};

void processAA( EventAA& a ){
   printf("Processing EventAA \n");
}

int main (){

   EventDriver <EventAA, EventBB, EventCC> ed;
   ed.setAction( &processAA );

   EventAA aa;
   ed.notify( aa );

   EventBB bb;
   ed.notify( bb );  // will display that no action registered
}
```

This works great. Now as a final part, I would like to set a default action for the case that an event action is not registered with driver. I would like to define a common templated function for default action:

```
template<class E>
void processAnyEvent( E& a ){
   printf("Processing Event %s \n", a.toString(); );
}
```

and register it using a method in `EventDriver
  ed.setDefaultAction( & processAnyEvent );`
which will get invoked in case no registered action found.

I found it extremely difficult implement this requirement and getting many compiler errors. I am using gcc version 6.3.0 , c++ 14

What should be the type of default_action member variable?
What should be the signature for `EventDriver::setDefaultAction` function?
Any other way to implement this?

Comment: What's `template < class ... ES >` mean?

Answer (score 1):

What about default initializing `action` as follows ?

```
std::tuple<Func<ES>...> actions { &processAnyEvent<ES>... };
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask for a way to pass different default handlers to different objects.

The problem is that a template functions as

```
template <typename E>
void processAnyEvent (E &)
 { std::cout << "Generic Processing Event"; }
```

isn't a single function but a set of function. `EventDriver` needs all of them (or, at least, one for every template parameter) and I don't know a simple way to pass set of function pointer.

The best I can imagine is to write some `struct`s with a template `static` `func()` method in it as

```
struct genEv1
 {
   template <typename E>
   static void func (E &)
    { std::cout << "Generic Processing Event 1"; }
 };

struct genEv2
 {
   template <typename E>
   static void func (E &)
    { std::cout << "Generic Processing Event 2"; }
 };
```

You can pass it as first template argument in `EventDriver`

```
EventDriver<genEv1, EventAA, EventBB, EventCC>  ed;
```

and use it to default initialize `actions`

```
template <typename GPES, typename ... ES>
struct EventDriver
 {
   // ...
   std::tuple<Func<ES>...>  actions{ &GPES::template func<ES>... };
   // ...
 };
```

Another way is to pass the `struct` with template `func()` generic handler as constructor parameter

```
 EventDriver<EventAA, EventBB, EventCC>  ed{ genEv1{} };
```

adding a template constructor in `EventDriver`

```
template <typename ... ES>
struct EventDriver
 {
   // ...
   std::tuple<Func<ES>...>  actions;

   template <typename GPES>
   EventDriver (GPES const &) : actions{ &GPES::template func<ES>... }
    { }
   // ...
};
```

Observe that if you pass `genEv1` as template parameter, two `EventDriver` object with different default handler are object of different types where, if `genEv1` is a constructor argument, are of the same type (when the `Es...` types are the same).

Comment: This works nice. But it restricts to hard corded one default implementation. In my case user will create multiple instances of EventDriver and like to set different default functions. I tried void setDefault( auto f ){ actions = { f<ES>..;} ; }. C++ doesn't allow.

Comment: one hack is ed.actions = std::make_tuple( processAnyEvent<EventAA>, processAnyEvent<EventBB>, processAnyEvent<EventCC> );

Comment: @shajen - sorry but ... are you sure to understand how template packs are instantiated? For `EventDriver <EventAA, EventBB, EventCC> ed;`... `std::tuple<Func<ES>...> actions { &processAnyEvent<ES>... };` is expanded in `std::tuple<Func<EventAA>, Func<EventBB>, Func<EventCC>> actions { &processAnyEvent<EventAA>, &processAnyEvent<EventBB>, &processAnyEvent<EventCC> };`

Comment: yes, I understood expansion. But I did this way because now users can have multiple instances, say,  EventDriver< EventAA, EventBB> ed1 ; EventDriver <EventP, EventQ> ed2; and then use their own default handlers ed1.actions = std::make_tuple( processAnyEventV1<EventAA>, &prorcessAnyV1<EventBB>);  and ed2.actions = std::make_tuple( &processAnyEventV2<EventP> &processAnyEventV2<EventQ> ) . Where processAnyEventV1 and processAnyEventV2 are two different funtions.

Comment: @shajen - not sure to understand... do you want different default handler for different instances of `EventDriver`? If so, do you want pass the default handler as (first?) template paramer? Or as a (template?) parameter to constructor?

Comment: yes, I want different default handler for different instances of EventDriver.  I tried with a member function setDefaultAction( f ) in EventDriver but could not implement.

Comment: @shajen - understand... no, I don't think `setDefaultAction(f)` can work... maybe `setDefaultAction<f>()` but I don't know exaclty how... an idea: it's OK if default handler are `static` template method inside a `class`/`struct`?

Comment: How to pass default action as template argument?

Comment: @shajen - the problem I'm trying to understand isn't "how?" but "what?". You can't pass a template function pointer; a template function is like a set of overloaded function and you can manage (pointer to function) only a single function, not set of functions. If you accept to pass a `struct` (say `struct A`), with a template static method in it, you can pass it in list of template parameter of object (`EventDriver<A, EventAA, EventBB>`) or as constructor parameter (`EventDriver<EventAA, EventBB> foo(A{});` or template parameter for `setDefaultAction()`

Comment: If c++ had allowed to pass templated function, I could expanded it inside EventDriver. It is really useful in many situations like this.

Comment: @shajen - answer modified to give you a first example (another one will follows, if no complications arise).

Comment: @shajen - second example added.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but the path is a bit windy.

First off, taking a pointer to the name of a function which is an overloaded function and/or a function template is not allowed except in certain circumstances where the compiler is able to determine just one actual function type will be used.  So `&func_name` will never represent something callable with multiple types.

But C++ does have a thing callable with multiple types: any class object (called a functor) which has overloaded and/or template member functions named `operator()`.  So let's make `setDefaultAction` a template member function that accepts any such functor, as long as it can be called with all the possible event types.

But we'll want to store a copy of that functor in the class.  `setDefaultAction` can be a function template, but we don't want to make class `EventDriver` require a template parameter for it, so we'll need some sort of "type erasure" technique.  [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) should be helpful, as it can store any type of functor and forward calls to it.  (`std::function` is a generalization of the idea of a pointer to function that represents anything that can be used like a function, including pointers to functions, functors, and pointers to class members.)

Still, using `std::function` requires a specific argument list type (and return type), so we can't just declare a `std::function` that can take any event type.  Luckily within the context of a `EventDriver` specialization, we have a finite list of possible types.  And C++17 has a class for representing "a value with any type chosen from a finite list of possible types": [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).  This goes along with the function [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to call a given functor with the current value in a `variant`.

Except the parameter type we want is a reference to event type, and `std::variant` does not allow storing references directly.  There are a couple of reasonable workarounds:

- Store [`std::reference_wrapper<E>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead of `E&`.  Create the reference wrapper objects when creating a `variant`, and get out the actual reference when calling the functor.
- Store `E*` instead of `E&`.  Take the address of the event when creating a `variant`, and dereference again when calling the functor.

They're about the same amount of work, and I think `reference_wrapper` is a little more clear about showing the intention, so that's the way I'll demonstrate.

Putting all the above together:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template < class ... ES >
class EventDriver {
public :
    // ...
    template<class T> using Func = std::function<void(T&)>;

    std::tuple< Func< ES > ... > actions;

    using VariantType = std::variant< std::reference_wrapper<ES>... >;
    std::function<void(const VariantType&)> default_action;

    template < typename F >
    void setDefaultAction( F func ) {
        auto unwrap_and_call = [func]( auto& ref )
            { func( ref.get() ); };
        default_action = [unwrap_and_call]( const VariantType& v )
            { std::visit( unwrap_and_call, v ); };
    }

    template < class EVENT >
    void notify( EVENT& e ){
        Func<EVENT> f = std::get< Func<EVENT> >( actions );

        if ( f ) {
            f( e );
        } else if ( default_action ) {
            default_action( std::ref( e ) );
        } else {
            std::cout << "Could not process event."
                " No registered action found \n";
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

And now it works.  Note that a function pointer is just as valid an argument to `setDefaultAction` as a class type functor, if you still like using some plain named functions.

But next I'm going to recommend an additional change.  Since functors are more flexible than pointers to function, and the class now accepts any functor for `setDefaultAction`, why not allow functors in `setAction` as well?

Making the change from `using Func = void (*)(T&)` to `using Func = std::function<void(T&)>` is the easy part.  The trouble this time is it isn't so simple to determine the event type from a general functor `F func` as it was from a function pointer `void (*fp)(EVENT&)`, and we need that to know which `tuple` slot to store the functor in.

I won't walk through my solution to that issue in complete detail, but the basic ideas are:

- Use a `std::enable_if` in the `setAction` function signature to make sure `F` can be invoked with exactly one of the possible event types.
- Given that we know exactly one event type is invokable, define a helper trait struct to get that event type.  It uses recursion to build the result from doing one check at a time.

A complete working example:

```
// #include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

namespace EventDriverPrivate {
    template <typename F, class ArgTuple, typename Enable=void>
    struct find_invocable_arg;
    template <typename F, class E0, class ... ERest>
    struct find_invocable_arg<F, std::tuple<E0, ERest...>,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable<F&, E0&>::value>>
    {
        using type = E0;
    };
    template <typename F, class E0, class ... ERest>
    struct find_invocable_arg<F, std::tuple<E0, ERest...>,
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable<F&, E0&>::value>>
    {
        using type = typename find_invocable_arg<F, std::tuple<ERest...>>::type;
    };

    template <typename F, class ... ES>
    using find_invocable_arg_t =
        typename find_invocable_arg<F, std::tuple<ES...>>::type;
}

template < class ... ES >
class EventDriver {
  public :
    template<class T> using Func = std::function<void(T&)>;

    std::tuple< Func< ES > ... > actions;

    using VariantType = std::variant< std::reference_wrapper<ES>... >;
    std::function<void(const VariantType&)> default_action;

    template < typename F,
        std::enable_if_t<(... + std::is_invocable<F&, ES&>::value) == 1, int> =0 >
    void setAction ( F func ) {
        std::get< Func< EventDriverPrivate::find_invocable_arg_t<F, ES...> > >
            ( actions ) = std::move(func);
    }

    template < class EVENT, typename F >
    void setActionFor ( F func ) {
        std::get< Func<EVENT> >( actions ) = std::move(func);
    }

    template < typename F >
    void setDefaultAction( F func ) {
        auto unwrap_and_call = [func]( auto& ref )
            { func( ref.get() ); };
        default_action = [unwrap_and_call]( const VariantType& v )
            { std::visit( unwrap_and_call, v ); };
    }

    template < class EVENT>
    void notify( EVENT& e ){
        Func<EVENT> f = std::get< Func<EVENT> >( actions );

        if ( f ) {
            f( e );
        } else if ( default_action ) {
            default_action( std::ref( e ) );
        } else {
            std::cout << "Could not process event. No registered action found \n";
        }

    }
};

// TEST the EventDriver
//
class EventAA{};
class EventBB{};
class EventCC{};

void processAA( EventAA& ){
   std::cout << "Processing EventAA \n";
}

int main (){
   EventDriver <EventAA, EventBB, EventCC> ed;
   ed.setAction( &processAA );

   ed.setAction( [](EventBB&) { std::cout << "Processing EventBB\n"; } );

   ed.setDefaultAction( [](auto& e)
       { std::cout << "Default action got type "
                   << typeid(e).name() << "\n"; } );

   EventAA aa;
   ed.notify( aa );

   EventBB bb;
   ed.notify( bb );

   EventCC cc;
   ed.notify( cc );
}
```

[Run and/or edit this program on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e5d96a3647cd46)

I also defined a function that can be used like `ed.setActionFor<EventXX>(handler);`.  This could be useful if you have some functor that is actually invokable for more than one event type.  The `enable_if_t` requiring exactly one invokable event type would fail, and we wouldn't want the compiler to automatically guess which event slot to use anyway, but instead this alternate function lets you specify what event you want to use the handler for.

One shortcoming in this `setAction` generalization, though: If it's supposed to be possible for one event type to use a different event type in the same `EventDriver`'s list as a base class, the requirement for only one invokable event type won't work, since a handler meant for a base event would also be invokable with an event derived from that base class.  In that case, it would be possible to come up with some more complicated template helpers to look for one invokable event type which is more derived than all other invokable event types....

Comment: Nice effort, and good to know in C++ 17 added features to support this kind of requirements. My original EventDriver code was less than 15 lines and was easy to explains to developers. Now to support small extra feature setDefaultAction,  code became 70 lines and unrecognizable. I guess I will live with default hard-corded method. It is easy to maintain.